# If someone knows your SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:, how "dangerous" is that?

Tags: android, security, ssl, sha1

I'm new to android, I have seen many people hiding their SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. I have developed an app using google play services and shared it with someone. It has my SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in it. Can a hacker do any damage knowing my SHA-1 Certificate.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your threat model. What does your app do? Is it another flashlight app? Does it help dissidents communicate under an oppressive regime? If the latter, disclosure of information like the identity bound to a public key or its digest could lead to real world risk.

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning... Code signing in Android does not provide identity assurances or guarantees since the certificates are self-signed. The only thing it provides is continuity and proof of ownership so a developer can release subsequent versions of his/her app. If you lose the private key, then you will likely never be able to provide an update to your app.

Comment: thanks for reply @jww, i am using google maps services in app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The certificate fingerprint is calculated from the certificate. The certificate itself is public information and transferred in clear during the SSL/TLS handshake. Which makes the fingerprint public information too, i.e. there is usually no danger in having it known by others.

But one could probably construct a situation where this might be dangerous. For example if your application uses the fingerprint to verify that it connects to the correct site and this site is an illegal site and you know this. In this case one could probably try to associate you with illegal activities from the fact that you've included the fingerprint of this certificate in your application.

Comment: could you elaborate on how someone will associate me with illegal activity by using fingerprint of my public key? How about writing down my name wouldn't it be the same? This is not the way public key cryptography works. BTW: here is fingerprint of stackoverflow - ‎47 ad b0 36 49 a2 eb 18 f6 3f fa 29 79 08 18 34 9a 99 ca b7

Comment: @MarekVitek: I think you interpret my answer in a way which was not intended. The first part clearly says that usually there is no danger. The second part then describes a theoretical situations where finding pinning to a specific certificate in an application can associate the author of the application with illegal activity. It does not claim that using the fingerprint of your certificate by someone else will associate you with illegal activity.

Comment: Certificate fingerprint is just bunch of random numbers. In that information is nothing about you. Information about you is in the public certificate you are making available. If your application is signed and doing something illegal, then it doesn't make any difference whether you publish certificate fingerprint or not. BTW: to verify whether you connect to right site you doesn't check your own certificate but that site's certificate / fingerprint.

Comment: @MarekVitek: again, you are interpreting my response in the wrong way. I do not claim that publishing *your own* fingerprint makes others associate you with illegal activity but that including the fingerprint of an illegal site (again, not yours) in your application might be used to associate you with illegal activity.

Comment: oh I see. Yes, having hard-coded any link to illegal activity in your application, including fingerprint of their certificate can point to your involvement. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No they can't do any harm to you by knowing this information.
In public key cryptography there are two pieces of information that are used for encryption and decryption of data. Private key, that you have and are not sharing with anyone, and public key. You can share public key with others, so they can send you encrypted data.
SHA1 fingerprint is just fingerprint of that public key, so anyone having your public key, can verify that it is really your key and not someone else.