# How SHA and SHA1 certificates secure an API on your Android app like Facebook does?

Tags: android, security, facebook-graph-api, sha1, sha

I know what is a SHA and SHA1 cryptographic algorithm. I also know how to genarate these from a computer.

But I have searched a lot on the internet and still unable to get a proper explanation on how using these keys will secure an API that you are using on an Android app?

For example, Facebook needs your SHA1 key from your system along with your app's package name to be entered on their developer console and their API doesn't work on your app if the key you entered is wrong.

How does this mechanism work? How do they verify this on your App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is leveraging [Android application signing functionality](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/) to provide the same type of assurance in the context of API interactions.

When building your application, your private key is being used to digitally sign the result. The signature validates that the build was created by the key owner and not subsequently modified.

Within the application, a signing certificate is stored, which is programmatically accessible.

In the Facebook SDK, [the signing certificate is extracted](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/791fa1fb5749e5069168698f17d78f21c1b4369c/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L728) using the [PackageManager class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager). The resultant keyhash is [provided as a parameter to API calls](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/8cb6f95df8d2763f67e136eb7b2a66d9ddfc5157/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/internal/ServerProtocol.java#L110), where it is compared with [the hash you provided via their Developer ste](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#samples).

So, by providing the keyhash out-of-band (i.e. exporting it and entering on the developer site), Facebook is able to validate the in-band instance (i.e. compiled into the application and included in API requests).

Comment: thanks a lot. I was searching for this answer from a long time. If you can, can you provide me with a detailed post or something like that ? Pardon my inabilities for not getting enough info on these.

Comment: The first link I provided provides a general description of the concept, then the [next section goes into greater detail about the signature scheme and validation algorithm](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2). There's also the [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) that goes into process details from the developer perspective.

Comment: Would you happen to know if a similar mechanism exists in iOS?

Comment: @chuckx I have a doubt , but this signing certificate can be hardcoded by modifying the app and resigning again . Am I correct ?

Comment: @AnanthuSubramanian The normal workflow assumes that the APK intended to be distributed is signed using the developers private key. When publishing an updated version of an application (which presumably has some modifications such as bug fixes, new features, etc.), a new signing certificate would be generated which proves authenticity. A third party who attempts to modify a signed APK would invalidate the signature. In that case, a new valid signature can't be created unless you have the private key.

Comment: @chuckx Thanks for the reply , but as we can extract the signing certificate using  PackageManager class . Is it possible to extract signing certificate of an app (SHA key) from any other app or using adb or something ? If so then , SHA can be hardcoded and can call the api isnt , by modifiying facebook sdk ? As I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577162/if-someone-knows-your-sha-1-certificate-fingerprint-how-dangerous-is-that) and it says SHA is public