# Is there a name for the technique of using a KeyStore/KeyChain for client authentication to APIs?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, cryptography

Is there a name for the kind of client authentication companies like Google and Facebook do for their SDKs?

For example, when configuring the Facebook SDK, [you're asked to provide a "key hash" in their application management dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#release-key-hash):

[image: not a real hash]

I'm curious to know if I can leverage this technique for my own APIs so that rather than storing a `client_id` and `client_secret` for my service, I can incorporate a similar kind of hash check.
Of course, knowing if it has a name will help me in my research to make sure I don't make mistakes or reinvent the wheel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997849/how-sha-and-sha1-certificates-secure-an-api-on-your-android-app-like-facebook-do

Answer (score 0):

If it was just a secret or private key that was exported and hashed then you could call it a *Key Check Value* or KCV.

However, it seems to me that this simply generates a signature over the certificate - which contains the public key - instead. In that case you would call the result the *fingerprint* of the certificate. This fingerprint can be used for something we call *certificate pinning*, which just allows a single certificate to be used.

If you would import it into a Windows keystore and you'd look at the certificate details then you should see the same fingerprint. However, generally the fingerprints are encoded into hexadecimals instead of base 64.