# Is it safe to share SHA-256 hash of app signing with someone else?

Tags: flutter, dart, sha256, sha1, sha

Recently I shared my SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys with someone while incorporating Google Sign-in through Firebase in a Flutter app.

While I read in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577162/if-someone-knows-your-sha-1-certificate-fingerprint-how-dangerous-is-that) that it's not too unsafe to share the SHA-1 key, I couldn't find this info about SHA 256.

I am not too familiar with security certificates and keys and I am just wondering if somebody else can somehow misuse the SHA 256 key in any kind of harmful way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as this question is too broad and open-ended. Please link to the "other answer" you read, and explain why you assume that sharing one type of key over another is safer? Who did you share the key with? How did you incorporate the key?

Comment: @slhck I have link the other answer in the question.  Also i am not assuming sharing one type of key over another is safer, just that sha-1 seems not too unsafe to share though there are scenarios where it can be misused. My only question is if somebody knows both the keys is it dangerous from security POV?

Comment: @slhck It's wrong to close the question willy nilly without waiting for any kind of clarification or elaboration as it severely limits the chance of getting an answer for the OP. This is one drawback of SO. Please reopen the question so somebody else can reply

Comment: It's not wrong to close a question if it's unclear as-is; it can always be reopened. Indeed you've added the link, which makes the whole context more clear. Voted to reopen. Do note though that you are talking about *fingerprints* here. The word "key" is a bit ambiguous. Have you read https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing already?

Comment: Also, the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44577517/435093) from the question you linked should also apply here. These fingerprints represent the same information.