# Is it safe to place sha256_cert_fingerprints in open url?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Google Play need the json file with sha256_cert_fingerprints in assetlinks.json file by particular url. I understand that it is needed to prove that I own this domain name. But is it safe to public sha256_cert_fingerprints? For example, I want to show this key to someone else. And this url is not secret from anyone.
I did not find any explanation how this key could be potentially used

Comment: Hi, I thinking is the same question as you. Do u find the answer?

Comment: @JackyTeaw, I did not. I just put that key in a proper url, Google checked this and my deeplinks work now.

Comment: Hi Foenix, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577162/if-someone-knows-your-sha-1-certificate-fingerprint-how-dangerous-is-that

I had read this question, so it said it is safe to place at open url.